# Como adicionar link ao comentário?

Tags: suporte

Até hoje ainda não consigo adicionar um "*link* formatado" aos meus comentários.

Entendo que o código `<a href="http://www.google.com/">isso não dá certo</a>` deveria criar um *link* para o texto especificado ("*isso não dá certo*"), porém o resultado é como o mostrado abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acredito que exista um componente da caixa de comentário que não permita que *links* sejam criados desta maneira, mas se possível gostaria de saber **como devo fazer** para que meus comentários fiquem mais legíveis.

Comment: `[exemplo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6800/28595)` => [exemplo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6800/28595)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O [@Articuno já respondeu](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6800/como-adicionar-link-ao-coment%C3%A1rio#comment26224_6800), mas gostaria de indicar a documentação/help, segue o link com todas formatações de comentários:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

### Formatação de comentários

Os comentários aceitam apenas **negrito**, *itálico*, código e links; além disso alguns links abreviados estão disponíveis.

```
texto em _itálico_ e **negrito**,
`código entre acentos graves` em linha
e `[links básicos]`(http://example.com).
```

Links abreviados compatíveis:

- `[meta]` – link para o site Meta atual; o texto do link é o nome do site (por ex. "Super Meta do usuário"). Não faz nada se o site não tiver (ou já for) um site Meta.
- `[main]` – como `[meta]` e vice-versa.
- `[edit]` – link para a página de edição para a publicação onde está o comentário, ou seja, `/publicações/{id}/editar`. O texto do link é "editar" (as maiúsculas são respeitadas).
- `[tag:tagname]` e `[meta-tag:tagname]` – link para a página da tag específica. O texto do link é o nome da tag.meta-tag funciona apenas em sites meta.
- `[help]`, `[help/on-topic]`, `[help/dont-ask]`, `[help/behavior]` e `[meta-help]` – link para páginas da central de ajuda visitadas com frequência. O texto do link é "central de ajuda" (as maiúsculas são respeitadas). Todos os links apontam para o site principal.
- `[tour]` – link para o Tour. O texto do link é "tour" (as maiúsculas são respeitadas)
- `[so]`, `[pt.so]`, `[su]`, `[sf]`, `[metase]`, `[a51]`, `[se]` – link para o site específico. O texto do link é o nome do site.
- `[chat]` – um link para o site de chat do site atual, com o texto "Chat do {site name}".
- `[ask]`, `[answer]` – link para a página Como perguntar ou Como responder.
- `[mcve]` – link to /help/mcve, with the link text "exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável".
- `[algo.se]` – link para algo.stackexchange.com, se esse site existir. O texto do link é o nome do site. Use `[ubuntu.se]` para Ask Ubuntu.

### Respondendo aos comentários

O proprietário da publicação em que você estiver comentando sempre será notificado do seu comentário. Se você estiver respondendo a alguém que anteriormente comentou na mesma publicação, mencione o nome de usuário dele: `@peter` e `@PeterSmith` notificarão alguém que tenha feito comentários com o nome “Peter Smith”.

Geralmente é suficiente mencionar apenas o primeiro nome do usuário cujo comentário você estiver respondendo, por ex. `@ben` ou `@marc`. No entanto, talvez deva ser mais específico se três pessoas chamadas Ben tiverem respondido em comentários anteriores, adicionando o primeiro caractere do sobrenome, por ex. `@benm` ou `@benc` Os espaços não são válidos nos nomes em respostas a comentários, portanto não use `@peter smith`, sempre use `@peters` ou `@petersmith`.

Se o usuário ao qual você está respondendo não tem um nome e sobrenome natural, simplesmente insira caracteres suficientes do nome para deixar claro para quem você está respondendo. Três é o mínimo, portanto se você estiver respondendo para Fantástico, insira `@fan`, `@fant`, ou `@fantastic`.

Você pode usar o mesmo método para notificar qualquer editor da publicação, ou – se for o caso – para o `♦` moderador que encerrou a pergunta.